# Calling Runnable out of Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
        // first work
        ThreadPool.getInstance().runNew(new MyClass());
        // second work
    }

}
```

What will happen if I create a new instance of MyClass inside of MyClass and send it to ThreadPoolExecutor? I want it to be infinity loop with only one instance working at time. Will the first thread reach "second work" immediately or will it wait until the next thread is finished?

Comment: Add `System.out.println("echo");` statements, then run it and see...

Comment: This depends on the implementation of the executor. Since there is no class `ThreadPool` in the standard API, we can’t know.

Comment: Just a wild guess - `StackOverflow` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve as Holger says, the answer depends entirely on what ThreadPool.getInstance().runNew() does with the new object.  If it actually _is_ a thread pool, then there won't be a stack overflow.

Comment: public void runNew (Runnable pkt){ threadPool.execute(pkt); } , and _threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

Comment: In that case, the new job will *not* wait but most likely run in another thread concurrently. If you want a one after another behavior, you have to either, use a [single thread executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()), or synchronize/lock on an instance-independent (i.e. `static`) object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it'd run until a new `Thread` can't be created.

The JVM would then throw:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:592)
```